# How to check the source of reset in ATMEGA644p

Tags: avr, atmega, atmel, reset, atmel-studio

I am trying to find the source of reset for ATMEGA644p, but I couldn't find the way to do it!

MCUCSR gives error in atmel studio as not declared and the datasheet also doesn't have it.

Comment: Did you read the parts that *are* in the datasheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [ATMEGA644p datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc7674.pdf) section 9.3.1 page 57 , there is the MCU Status Register **MCUSR** that provides information on which reset source caused an MCU reset.